# One problem with selection sort about the call of a founction? （python array）

Tags: python, arrays

```
# Selection sort

# find smallest 
def find_min(array):
    min_val = array[0]
    min_val_index = 0
    for i in range(1, len(array)):
        if array[i] < min_val:
            min_val = array[i]
            min_val_index = i
    return min_val_index

# selection sort
def selection_sort(array):
    new_array = []
    for i in range(len(array)):
        min_val = find_min(array)
        new_array.append(array.pop(min_val))
    return new_array

# array = [1,3,6,14,35,3,6]         # ①
# selection_sort(array)             # ②

selection_sort([4,2,5,6,7,9,1,8,3,10])  # ③
```

Question：

There is something wrong when I use ①+② instead of ③  （③ is correct）
I don't know their differences.
I have tried the same array but did not help.
Here is the Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-f31e6df2662f> in <module>
     16 
     17 array = [1,3,6,14,35,3,6]
---> 18 selection_sort(array)
     19 # selectSort([4,2,5,6,7,9,1,8,3,10])

<ipython-input-90-f31e6df2662f> in selection_sort(array)
     12     for i in range(len(array)):
     13         min_val = find_min(array)
---> 14         new_array.append(array.pop(min_val))
     15     return new_array
     16 

IndexError: pop index out of range
```

Comment: I assume (3) should be `selection_sort([...])`? And have you tried it with the same arrays instead of different ones?

Comment: print(sorted([4,2,5,6,7,9,1,8,3,10]))

Comment: I copy pasted your code with (1) and (2) and had to change `def find_min_val(array):` to `def find_min(array):` as it is used in the other function and then the code works fine for me

Comment: yes , I  have tried, not working. ③ is the correct way.

Comment: Thank you Leo ,work  it out!  @LeoE

Comment: Yes, that's a good way . Actually, I am trying to understand the function rather than use it . @Alexall